# Financial Analysis from CSV File

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, finance

I need to calculate the following data from a CSV file for a project.

```
Financial Analysis
  ----------------------------

  Total Months: 86
  Total: $38382578
  Average  Change: $-2315.12
  Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 ($1926159)
  Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 ($-2196167)
```

I've already imported pandas and numpy. I made pandas read the csv and print the data.

This is the csv file:
[image: CSV File]

This is what I have so far in Jupyter Lab:
[image: code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: It would help to see what the csv looks like to get an idea of what you need to do. 
You should also describe how you should get to your results. Do you use Excel or calc of libreoffice or openoffice or just deal with the csv using python and then pandas and numPy? Do you have an idea of how to approach it, some code you wrote already?

Comment: just added CSV file

Comment: Right now in the class we are just dealing with the csv using python and then pandas and numPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and pass the required functions as a `List[str]`.

```py
df.agg(["count", "max", "mean","min"])
```

From what is visible in your screenshot, I get the following output.

**Output:**

```
           Date  Profit/Losses
count        25           25.0
max    Sep-2011      1033096.0
mean        NaN       432313.2
min    Apr-2010      -755566.0
```